# How can I call a service from a template in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a service that returns a json object that it makes, for brevity lets say it looks like this:

```
.service ('levelService', function () {

    // service to manage levels.
    return  {
        levels : [{name:'Base', href:'base'},{name:'Level 1', href:'level1'},{name:'level2', href:'level2'}]
    };

})
```

I think that is fine, but I want to use it now, in a template.  Currently I have something like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-init="levels = [{name:'Base', href:'base'},{name:'Level 1', href:'level1'},{name:'level2', href:'level2'}];">
                      <li ng-repeat="level in levels">
      <a ng-href="#/modeling/level/{{level.href}}">{{level.name}}</a></li>
                  </ul>
```

How can I get the ng-init to now use the service?  I feel like the right thing to do, is add the service to the controller, but this is outside of any controller.  Do i need to create a new controller for this space, or can i directly reference the service?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it would be best practice to create a controller.

The idea behind the MVC app architecture is that you don't tightly couple your objects/classes together. Injecting a service into a controller, then subsequently your controller adding `levels` to `$scope` means that your HTML doesn't have to worry about where it gets the data from.

Also, using `ng-init` in that way is arguably fine for knocking up a very quick prototype, but that approach shouldn't be used in production code (as your model's data itself is tightly coupled to your view's HTML).

Tip: It might be a good idea to use a controller for the parent container of your `dropdown-menu` (ie. the page/section) and then use a directive for your `dropdown-menu` itself. Think of a directive as a view component.

In general, you might find the video tutorials at [egghead.io](http://www.egghead.io/) helpful.

Comment: thanks!  Took your advice, instead of making a directive, just made another controller.

Answer (score 6):

put the service in a controller..
Then you can call service in your template..

```
app.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope, levelService) {
   $scope.levelService= levelService;
});
```