# Call service method from ngClick directly without calling the controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-ng-click

I have an AngularJS service as shown below:

```
.service('CommonProp', function ($location) {
    return {
        log: function () {
            // Do stuff
        }
    };
});
```

I'm calling the above method `log` from a controller function which is invoked from a ngClick on an anchor tag.

```
$scope.calllog = function(){
    CommonProp.log();
}
```

HTML code:

```
<a ng-click="callog()" />
```

In the above code, the controller function is doing nothing much except calling the service method. Is there a way to call service method from the ng click directive without calling the controller function.

Comment: You can add methods to the `$rootScope`. You could do it on the `angular.run` section of your module

Comment: [How can I call a service from a template in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901553/how-can-i-call-a-service-from-a-template-in-angularjs)

Comment: Also you can just do `$scope.calllog = CommonProp.log;`

Comment: better you could also do `$scope.calllog = CommonProp` that would available all the service method on html

Comment: @pankajparkar what if I want to use that service method across different views. In that case I would have to declare `$scope.calllog = CommonProp` in each controller.

Comment: @iJade: See, there is a controllers hierarchy in angular aplication, usually we create a main controller usually at the level where ng-app is declared, and all the controllers become the children-like of the main controller. Now, if your function is so common that it is being used in lot of places , then put it in the mainController(from where it calls the service) and you can call it directly from any template